# How can I curl 127.0.0.1/8000 while django development server is running?

Tags: django, shell, docker

I have never ran into this before because I can always just run the dev server, open up a new tab in terminal and curl from there.  I can't do this now because I am running the Django Development server from a Docker container and so if I open a new tab, I will be in the local shell and not the docker container.

How can I leave the development server running and still be able to curl or run other commands?

When I run the development server I'm left with this message:

```
Django version 1.10.3, using settings 'test.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

and so unable to type any commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `&` to run the server as a background job in the current shell:

```
$ python manage.py runserver &
[1] <pid>
$
```

You can use the `fg` command to get back direct control over the `runserver` process, then you can stop it as usual using `Ctrl+C`.

To set a foreground process as a background job, you can pause it using `Ctrl+Z`, and run the `bg` command. You can see a list of running backgrounds job in the current shell using the `jobs` command.

The difference with `screen` is that this will run the server in the current shell. If you exit the shell, the server will stop as well, while `screen` uses a separate process that will continue after you exit the current shell.

Comment: when I run this, I do see [1] 19 underneath.  However, beneath that it still show the development server message and so I cannot type any commands.

Comment: @david Don't let the output distract you. The server is running in the background, but still writing to your current shell. If you don't have a valid prompt. simply hit `Enter` and it should appear again.

Answer (score 0):

In a development environment you can do following also.

1. Let the server run in one terminal window.
2. Open a new terminal window/tab and run
   `docker exec -it <Container ID/Name> /bin/bash`
   It will give you interactive access to your container, i.e. you can execute any command in your container rather than in your local shell.

Type `exit` to come out container shell to local shell.